# Swift: SKAction not working on touch

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

Ive been trying to follow along swift tutorials and I've come across something extremely frustrating with every tutorial I have tried to follow along with, whenever SKAction is used I cannot follow along with any tutorials because my programs never work. This has happened with MULTIPLE programs and I can never figure it out.

Here is the code for the program:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene{

let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerShip")

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    background.size = self.size
    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
    background.zPosition = -1
    self.addChild(background)


    player.setScale(1)
    player.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height * 0.2)
    player.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(player)


}

func fireBullet(){

    let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
    bullet.setScale(1)
    bullet.zPosition = 1
    bullet.position = player.position

    let moveBullet = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height + bullet.size.height, duration: 1)
    let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveBullet, deleteBullet])
    bullet.run(bulletSequence)

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    fireBullet()
}

}
```

Whenever I build and run the program in the simulator everything is fine and the build succeeds. However whenever I click nothing happens, this happens every single time I attempt to do anything with SKAction. I should mention that the FPS at the bottom right corner of my screen changes every time I click, but nothing else happens, the node count stays the same, and the screen remains the same with the bullet not firing.

Here is the tutorial I am attempting to follow along with: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvlwZs2ehLU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed you aren't actually adding the `bullet` sprite to your scene after instantiating it. Make sure to add `addChild(bullet)`. I suggest implementing something like this:

```
func fireBullet() {

    let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
    bullet.setScale(1)
    bullet.zPosition = 1
    bullet.position = player.position
    addChild(bullet)

    let moveBullet = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height + bullet.size.height, duration: 1.0)
    let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveBullet, deleteBullet])
    bullet.run(bulletSequence)

}
```

Comment: I copy pasted the code and once again no errors however just like before the only thing that changes is the fps. The node counter doesn't increase and no bullet appears.

Comment: @Richard Parker I just realized you need to add the bullet to the scene

Comment: @RichardParker - see my update let me know if that helps

Comment: Oh I was under the impression run took care of that. The person in the tutorial never used that, this must be a new addition with swift 3. I really appreciate the help, its difficult to get answers considering how everything I find is in swift 2 and its hard to come buy swift 3 specific solutions.

Comment: @RichardParker - No problem! Happy to help. It's a common mistake people make. It would have been necessary in Swift 2 also, but chances are that the person who made the tutorial accidentally left it out. If you want to learn how to make 2D games with Swift 3, I can recommend an awesome e-book that really helped me.

Comment: Id love the recommendation, Im trying to get as much experience before I go to college as possible so Im just trying to absorb all the information I can.

Comment: @RichardParker - It's a Ray Wenderlich book that teaches you how to program like 6 different complete games through tutorials. Even has a tutorial for how to create characters using Illustrator at the very end of the book. It's a great value IMO https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/2d-apple-games-by-tutorials

Comment: Also, something I should mention is that the waitAction is not necessary because the delete only happens after the moveBullet has finished.